# select the second instance of a class and display none

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have too many logout links on my forum. I don't want to display the second and third, I only want to display the first.

```
class = bbpresslogouturl
```

I tried:

```
.bbpressloginurl:nth-last-of-type(2){display:none;}
.bbpressloginurl:nth-last-of-type(1){display:none;}
```

but this hasn't worked using css. Is there a way to select the nth of class using jQuery?

Comment: `$('.bbpresslogouturl').not(':first').hide()`

Comment: `:nth-last-of-type` cares **only** about element type. There is no `:nth-of-class` in CSS. You will have to resort to Javascript.

Comment: use `:nth-child() or .eq()` not that `.eq()` index starts at 0

Comment: as was said...use `nth-child` http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

Comment: Depending on your HTML structure there may be CSS-based solutions. Impossible to tell without us knowing the HTML.

Answer (score 6):

If they are not "brothers/siblings"

```
$('.bbpressloginurl').eq(1).hide();
```

If they are, you can use css: this will hide the next sibling

```
.bbpressloginurl:first-child + .bbpressloginurl{ display: none; }
```

This will hide all the next siblings.

```
.bbpressloginurl:first-child ~ .bbpressloginurl{ display: none; }
```

Or even this:

```
.bbpressloginurl:not(:first-child) { display: none; }
```

It depends on you markup, which you didn't share.. and also you existing css selectors

__

Also,
`first-of-type` and `last-of-type` can not be used on classnames, just elements ( ul, h2, .. )

Comment: The term is `siblings`, not brothers. Also, even if they were siblings it doesn't mean that the first of them is the first-child of its parent. And even if it were, you'd have to use the sibling slector `~` and not the neighboring selector `+`.

Comment: Which would be what OP wants, if their HTML structure would meet your requirements, which it hardly will. *I have too many logout links on my forum. I want to not display the second and third and only display the first.*

Comment: Not really, if you check out the title of the question... "select the second instance of a class and display none"; anyways i provided multiple solutions for many cases..

Comment: `.bbpressloginurl ~ .bbpressloginurl { display: none; }` was the only one that worked for me!

Comment: @BradTheBluefish again, it depends on your markup and existing CSS selectors

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<div class="test">
  1
</div>
<div class="test">
  2
</div>
<div class="test">
  3
</div>
```

and css:

```
.test {
  display: none;
}

.test:nth-child(1) {
  display: block !important;
}
```

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4kshL4s/)

Answer (score 1):

Hide all of them except the first with

```
$('.bbpresslogouturl').not(':first').hide();
```